# IntellitraceFile throwing strange error

Tags: c#, intellitrace, visual-studio-debugging

Can someone explain this error? (it showed up after enabling tracing in the collection plan.)

```
Test method ExecuteTaskTest threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.IntelliTraceProcess.AddModule(IntelliTraceModule module)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.IntelliTraceProcess.Initialize(IntelliTraceFile traceDebugLogFile)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.IntelliTraceProcess..ctor(IntelliTraceFile traceDebugLogFile)
**Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.IntelliTraceFile.get_Processes()**
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Samples.IntelliTraceReader..ctor(String logFileName) in C:\workspace\agileproductlinerdsl\ITraceLogParser\IntelliTraceReader.cs: line 49
UofCASE.AgileProductLinerDSL.Nant.AspenTest.writeTraceResult(FileInfo itraceLog, FileInfo resultFile) in C:\workspace\agileproductlinerdsl\NantTask\AspenTest.cs: line 148
UofCASE.AgileProductLinerDSL.Nant.AspenTest.runTests(FeatureTestMap tests) in C:\workspace\agileproductlinerdsl\NantTask\AspenTest.cs: line 124
UofCASE.AgileProductLinerDSL.Nant.AspenTest.ExecuteTask() in C:\workspace\agileproductlinerdsl\NantTask\AspenTest.cs: line 56
APLDTests.AspenTestTest.ExecuteTaskTest() in C:\workspace\agileproductlinerdsl\APLDTests\AspenTestTest.cs: line 37
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with IntelliTrace. The log file was likely collected from an app that had the same module loaded into multiple app domains and this causes IntelliTrace to barf when grabbing the Process list as you can see.