# IntelliTrace logs from Windows Azure Worker Role not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, load-testing, intellitrace

I've been trying to monitor my worker role using IntelliTrace, particularly during times when we've been subjecting to high load.

When I try to download the logs using Visual Studio, I get:

> Failed to open IntelliTrace log. Error message: System error.

Other times, when the log file has been downloaded another error is produced:
The operation could not be completed.

I've downloaded, [IntelliTraceReader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/iTraceReader) and while debugging, it pointed out that there's a problem with the logfile itself, declaring:

> An item with the same key has already been added

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569070/intellitracefile-throwing-strange-error) on SO pointing out that this may be a known issue, however, I'm not sure how to work around it. Any further recommendations than that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a case with Microsoft Support:

https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?&c1=501&gprid=14928&&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported action and actually conflicting the EULA of Visual Studio. I don't think you will get any different answer from MSFT.

Here is a quote from the EULA:

> The IntelliTrace DDA and/or IntelliTrace.exe cannot be used:
>
> - On a device or server in a production environment.
> - For purposes of system or application monitoring.
> - In non-interactive scenarios other than as part of an automated
>     test or debugging-data collection session.

And the full EULA is [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CIoBEBYwBA&url=http://www.micromail.com/files/admin/uploads/W285_Field_2_55626.pdf&ei=Z12oT-yAK4zN4QTYmIiVCQ&usg=AFQjCNE5Go7haLO0oDFSOTDoOvVz0xIVrA&sig2=tB2oLfMs53ygxWqdz4DMSg).

I suggest that you better intrument your application to closely monitor it. Or use any of the available on the market performance monitoring apps. Such as [NewRelic](http://www.newrelic.com), [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com/AzureWatch) and others.